# How to add an event handler to button from array in c++ CLI?

Tags: arrays, button, c++-cli

I have an array of buttons and I want to add an event handler for them.

My array:

`array<Button^>^ buttons = gcnew array<Button^>(10);`

There I try to add an event handler:

```
private: void tasksButtons_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    MessageBox::Show("Lol");
}
private: System::Void main_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    int horizontal = 0, vertical = 0;
    for each(Button^ i in buttons) {
        i = gcnew Button();
        i->Text = "i";
        i->Width = 20;
        i->Height = 20;
        horizontal += 20;
        i->Location = Point(horizontal, vertical);
        this->Controls->Add(i);
        i->Click += tasksButtons_Click;
    }
}
```

It gives me an error because of `i->Click += tasksButtons_Click`. What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard warning: While it's certainly possible to write the main body of your application in C++/CLI, or even write the GUI in C++/CLI using WinForms, it is not recommended. C++/CLI is intended for interop scenarios: where C# or other .Net code needs to interface with unmanaged C++, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. For primary development, it is recommended to use C# with either WinForms or WPF if you want managed code, or C++ with MFC if you want unmanaged.

---

In C++/CLI, you need to instantiate the delegate explicitly, use a C++-style reference to the method, and specify the object to call the method on (for non-static methods only)

```
i->Click += gcnew EventHandler(this, &MyForm::tasksButtons_Click);
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                   instantiate explicitly
//                             ^^^^                              specify the object to use
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ C++-style reference
```